# Simple multi-dimensional C-style array gives segmentation fault : 11

Tags: c++

```
const int L=10;
std::complex<double> c_array[L][L][L][L][L][L]    // 6 dimensions
```

Space needed: 2*8*10^6 bytes

It should not use up all of memory, right?

Comment: That's a very large array. I'd wager a stack overflow.

Comment: Is this a local variable?  If so, this all ends up on the stack, which may not be big enough.

Comment: Don't you think that maybe you could just do this with a 1-D array: `vector<complex<double>> c_array(1000000)`

Comment: That would be ~7.6MB for just doubles.  I am on my phone atm, but my bet is on a SO as well.

Comment: It's inside main(), and the only two line inside main(). Is there any solution for this? I have to store this array.

Comment: @user62367 Just don't store it on the stack - malloc the space for it and store it on the heap. 7.6MB is not that large for the heap but it is way too large for the stack.

Comment: @user62367 `vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<complex> > > > > > >` :P The point is, you need to heap-allocate it.

Comment: If it's a stackoverflow from the array being on the stack, make it a vector intead.

Comment: thank you for pointing it is a stack overflow. I never encounter this before, but I finally understood.

Comment: Do you *really* need 6 dimensions, though? That's the most absurd array I've ever seen.

Comment: My problem is calling a function inside a loop. The function has 6 parameters. For speed, I store all the values of this function for all possible parameters.

Comment: @chris there are mathematical applications for 6D.

Comment: @user62367 there *might* be other solutions to that problem than caching *every* possible outcome of the function in memory. If you provide the function an the problem it is supposed to solve in a new question, people might be able to help you with that.

Comment: @ArneMertz thanks. I post a new question about speed up function call inside loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529772/speed-up-function-call-inside-loop

Answer (score 8):

There is a stack size limit for every  processes. Therefore, if you really want to create this array locally (in the stack), the only solution is to increase the stack size limit for your program. How to change the stack size limit depends on your OS.

Alternative is to create this array in the heap. To do that you have to use "new" keyword as follows.

```
std::complex<double> *c_array = new std::complex<double>[L][L][L][L][L][L];
```

Comment: Might want to store that in a smart ptr.

Comment: I'd switch the alternatives. Increasing the stack is really unusual and can have serious system side-effects.

Comment: `error: cannot convert ‘std::complex<double> (*)[2][2][2][2][2]’ to ‘std::complex<double>*’ in initialization` - in short: just don't use multidimensional C-arrays, they're just hard to get used to.