# Speed up function call inside loop

Tags: c++, performance

```
loop over a very long container (millions elements)
{
   each element compute 8 integers:  k1,k2,k3,...,k8

   call function    func(k1,k2,k3,...,k8)
}

container is a std::vector, element is a long integer
each k can only take {0,1,2,..5} six values.
func is a simple expression of complex number calculation, 
  involves std::conj and std::exp
```

To speed up, I cache all possible outcome of 'func' to an array, and call func_array[k1][k2][k3]... instead.
But if simply define func_array as:
      std::complex  func_array[6][6][6]...,
the program dies on stack overflow.

Any better solutions to speed up?

Comment: Allocate your array on the heap ?

Comment: At this level, we need more information on your data structure : what is the container, what are the elements, what kind of computation you do to get the k… Continous memory might help a lot as the compiler will vectorize it

Comment: If I did not miss something, that's a 6^8 values array, which is about 2 million, so really not that much. Maybe just allocate an int[1679616] array, to avoid extra nested array allocation overhead ?

Comment: @C4stor multiply by 8 bytes or so and you're at 10 megs which might trounce some stacks.  Moving to class or global scope, or using a pointer would alleviate this pressure on the stack.

Comment: @ebyrob That really depends on the environment then. But I kinda assumed a standard modern computer, on which 10 megs is not a lot in my book.

Comment: @C4stor Looks like some Visual Studio compilers still default some threads to only 1 meg: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx  Stack is often at a premium, heap could be 16 gigs...  Or more simply if you've ever done Google Code Jam, how often did you have to move variables out of stack to avoid overflow without completely revamping your compiler options?

Comment: from wich range of values are the elements in the vector? You say they are of type long, but are there more restirctions? Is `func` in some sense symmetric in some of the arguments? (maybe provide the code)

Comment: @ebyrob : Very good point, I wouldn't have guessed only 1M for the stack by default. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If func() always returns the same value for a given set of inputs (e.g. not time-dependent, sequence dependent etc.), then you could do the following:

**1.** Whenever you call func(), save the result to a cache [using values of k1...through k8 as the key to the cache-entry]

**2.** Before calling func(), check if you already have the required value cached

The cache itself could be a Map, where you constuct the key by concatenating k1... thru ... k8 in some way that is appropriate to their data-type.

Comment: Doesn't a C++ multidimensional array behave pretty much like a hash map in terms of read-performance?  The only benefit I could see in a dynamic hash would be if input values outside the expected range of 0-5 were occuring.

Comment: He said he caches "all possible" outcomes. So, I think he is building a "8-dimensional" array of 6 values each, which means over a million entries. 

Assuming that's what he's doing, he needs to only cache before and after an actual usage.

Comment: @DariusX. Having a bucket doesn't necessarily mean that it's filled...  My understanding is only the buckets are pre-allocated.

Comment: Yup, but he said "I cache all possible outcome of 'func' to an array"
Anyhow, only the OP can clear up the mystery. Maybe I just read him wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an array of `std::complex[6][6]...[6]` on the
stack?  First, this could easily cause stack overflow: that's
a fairly large array for many stacks.  And second: if you create
it on the stack, it will be reinitialized each time you call the
function.  What you probably want is a local static array, which
will be initialized once (the first time it is encountered), and
then retain its value between function calls.

Comment: I cache it to a member variable, the loop is inside a member function.

Comment: `static std::complex func_array[6][6][6][6][6][6][6][6] = {0};` inside the class method then?

Comment: If the program is used a lot, and even better solution would be to calculate all of the values once, and output them as a C++ array initializer, so you could compile the fully initialized static into the program.  This may not be possible, however---I've had "out of memory" from the compiler at times with machine generated initializers.  Otherwise, write the binary data to a file, and `mmap` it.  (You'll need some tricky casting for that, but you can hide it in an inline function.)

Comment: That member will be `1679616*sizeof(std::complex)`. If you put that member inside an object that lives on the stack then you may well blow away your stack. You should either allocate the array dynamically inside the object (use `std::complex*`) or allocate the parent object with `new` instead of as a straight local variable.

Comment: @ams From his description, he should be able to define the object as a static const.  Provided his compiler doesn't blow up when it encounters 1679616 initializers.

Comment: @JamesKanze: sure, but that's not reentrant, and therefore poor practice.

Comment: @ams What do you mean, not reentrant.  It's perfectly reentrant.  (Not that this is an issue if the function itself isn't recursive.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: how can it be reentrant if it uses local data? OK, the cached contents *might* be applicable to all callers, but that's not specified, and you might need to add some kind of locking. Like you say though, if there is no recursion and only one thread then that's fine, but it's still something we should mention when giving advice.

Comment: @ams How does statically initialized, const local data affect reentrance?  The data is initialized when the program is loaded, and is never changed.  It can't have different cached contents, anywhere, since there aren't any different contents to cache.

Comment: @ams Note that if this wasn't the case, we'd have a real problem.  Since statically initialized, const local data is pretty much what the machine code for the program is.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Oh, you want to statically initialize the *entire* cache contents, not just allocate the storage?! I didn't see that initially because that's INSANE!

Comment: @ams Why is it insane?  You do it once, before compiling the code, rather than each time you run the program.  (I do similar things all the time, and I'm certainly not the only one.  Any number of widely used tools depend on it.)

Comment: A multi-megabyte lookup table? Sure, you could do that but it had better be an important improvement.

Comment: It's a ~12-MB lookup table (assuming sizeof(complex) == 8) either way, the question is just whether we prefill it or fill it up as we go. It's a trade-off between executable size and execution time. Actually the precomputed way would use *less* memory, since it doesn't need to have an additional array storing flags for whether a cache entry is filled.