# Max memory allocation?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, int, limit

Hi I'm trying to use this:

```
std::tr1::array<std::tr1::array<queue<Graphnode>,MAXCPU>,MasterBufferNo> checkQueue;
```

But if the MasterBufferNo or MAXCPU is too large(MAXCPU = 4, MasterBufferNo=30000), there will be an running error:

```
=====================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
=====================================================================================
```

I wonder how to limit out? or what is the problem? I need a array much larger than that... the size of Graphnode is 32 bytes.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17519544/583833

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` is a wrapper around statically-sized C arrays. That means this data will be allocated on the stack. There is an upper bound on how large your stack allocations can be. So your best bet is to make this dynamically allocated via `sdt::vector`.

One possibility:

```
std::vector<std::array<std::queue<Graphnode>,MAXCPU>> checkQueue(MasterBufferNo);
```

Comment: there is no way of using array on heap?

Comment: Statically allocated data can either be on stack (when inside a function) or global; it is not put on the heap. So you can make a global `std::array`, which *may* work, but then you'll lose scope. If you want the heap, go dynamically allocated. The good news is, as my sample line shows above, there isn't much you have to change.

Comment: So vector is a dynamic allocation which will allocate on heap instead of array which will allocate on stack?

Comment: That's correct. The main thing is that `std::vector` is dynamically sized and `std::array` is statically sized.

Comment: can I access the element int he vector like checkQueue[2][3] same as array? how's the accessing speed comparing to array?

Comment: or can I use new and delete to put it on the heap? is it the same thing?

Comment: I need fixed length to use this array as a buffer. once it is out of its size i can flush to the disk.